# Working with subdomain in google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, subdomain

How can I work with sub domain in google app engine (python).

I wanna get first domain part and take some action (handler).

**Example:**
     product.example.com  -> send it to products handler
     user.example.com     -> send it to users handler

Actually, using virtual path I have this code:

```
  application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
    [('/', IndexHandler),
     ('/product/(.*)', ProductHandler),
     ('/user/(.*)', UserHandler)
  ]
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

WSGIApplication isn't capable of routing based on domain. Instead, you need to create a separate application for each subdomain, like this:

```
applications = {
  'product.example.com': webapp.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', IndexHandler),
    ('/(.*)', ProductHandler)]),
  'user.example.com': webapp.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', IndexHandler),
    ('/(.*)', UserHandler)]),
}

def main():
  run_wsgi_app(applications[os.environ['HTTP_HOST']])

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Alternately, you could write your own WSGIApplication subclass that knows how to handle multiple hosts.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have some sample of this sub WSGIApplication to me? I'm stating with python...

Comment: Check out the source for the current one at http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/webapp/__init__.py - modifying the __call__ method to take into account the hostname should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: The code above doesn't seem to work in production with both subdomains linked to one GAE app. Did anybody get this to work?

Comment: Nick - How does this multiple-domain example work in the Python 2.7 runtime?  In app.yaml, I now specify the WSGI application directly.  So, would I instead specify the Python script in app.yaml and treat it as above or is there a more streamlined way of doing this directly with the WSGI application?

Comment: Nick - One more related question: How do you test/simulate these kinds of multi-domain applications on dev_appserver prior to deploying?  If all requests are coming in on localhost, how does the dev_appserver differentiate between the requests that are meant for the different subdomains?

Comment: @cv12 You can use your hostfile, or a DNS server, to associate multiple names with your local server. Or you can modify your WSGI middleware to accept some sort of 'host override' get parameter.

Comment: Nick - Thanks for your response to the second of my two questions in these comments.  I would very much appreciate if you could also answer the first one: How does this multiple-domain example work in the Python 2.7 runtime? In app.yaml, I now specify the WSGI application directly. So, would I instead specify the Python script in app.yaml and treat it as above or is there a more streamlined way of doing this directly with the WSGI application?

Comment: @cv12 Check out the documentation for webapp2; it has routers that support routing differently for different subdomains.

Answer (score 2):

I liked the idea from Nick but I had a slightly different issue.  I wanted to match one specific subdomain to handle it a bit different, but all other sub domains should be handled the same.  So here is my example.

```
import os

def main():
   if (os.environ['HTTP_HOST'] == "sub.example.com"):
      application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/(.*)', OtherMainHandler)], debug=True)
   else:
      application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler),], debug=True)

   run_wsgi_app(application)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```