# How do I test multiple domains setup in AppEngine locally?

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, subdomain, multiple-domains

In the question [Working with subdomain in google app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838078/working-with-subdomain-in-google-app-engine), the following code was suggested.

```
applications = {
  'product.example.com': webapp.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', IndexHandler),
    ('/(.*)', ProductHandler)]),
  'user.example.com': webapp.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', IndexHandler),
    ('/(.*)', UserHandler)]),
}

def main():
  run_wsgi_app(applications[os.environ['HTTP_HOST']])

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

My question is how do I test this locally? When I'm testing it locally, the host is "localhost:8080" and not any of the domains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two new entries in your [Hosts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file) file:

```
127.0.0.1       product.example.com
127.0.0.1       user.example.com
```

and run your local GAE application on default Http port 80.

If, for some reason, you can't run GAE on port 80, you could try to modify your `application.py` to match the local port number with something like this:

```
if os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE'].startswith('Dev'):
    PORT=':8080'
else:
    PORT=''

applications = {
  'product.example.com%s' % PORT: webapp.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', IndexHandler),
    ('/(.*)', ProductHandler)]),
  'user.example.com%s' % PORT: webapp.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', IndexHandler),
    ('/(.*)', UserHandler)]),
}
```

Or even better modifying the main function like this (Thanks to @Nick's comment):

```
def main():
  run_wsgi_app(applications[os.environ['HTTP_HOST'].split(':')[0]])
```

You should be ready to test your local application with the following addresses:
http://product.example.com:8080
http://user.example.com:8080

Remember to switch back your `Hosts` file to be able to reach the Production server.

Comment: ...or you could just go to http://product.example.com:8080/ after setting up the host file entries.

Comment: @Nick no, you can't. Hosts file does not allow to specify port information and.. pointing to product.example.com:8080 does not match any WSGIApplication.

Comment: @systempuntoout I'd forgotten HTTP_HOST includes a port number. A much better approach would be to remove the port number from the header before matching on it, though.

Comment: @Nick that would be another viable solution; though I'm not quite sure it is allowed in Production.

Comment: @systempuntoout Er? Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: @Nick How could you strip down a specific header before the request hits the application main? Probably we are talking about two different things. Why don't you post an example :)?

Comment: @systempuntoout: run_wsgi_app(applications[os.environ['HTTP_HOST'].split(':')[0]])

Comment: aaah Ok, I was thinking about some middleware complex solution. Yes I agree, your method is less invasive. (I have edited my answer accordingly)